# Chain state with struct return <unknown>

Tags: extrinsic

I am navigating by all the recipes, and I am playing with the structStorage.
When I save a struct on the storage, after I try to get from chain state, if I use polkadot.js UI, the value that I am getting is : .
If i u

```
Error: Unable to decode storage structStorage.innerThingsByNumbers: entry 1:: createType(InnerThingOf):: DoNotConstruct: Cannot construct unknown type InnerThingOf
```

Comment: What Substrate version are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With any recent Substrate chains based off Metadata v14, this is not needed - the metadata itself will be fully-specify will all types and their definitions.

For older versions of Substrate, you need to specify the types in the UI via Settings -> Developer. The metadata only exposes the names of the types and the UI would need to know what type it is to [construct it](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.create#choosing-how-to-create).